# Notepad++ macro for changing a certain part of a string

Tags: notepad++, search, macros, string, string-manipulation

I want to define a Notepad++ macro that takes any string that contains "foo", and creates its new versions only changing the foo to "bar1", "bar2" etc.

so if my file contains

```
abc_foo_def
```

when I run the macro, I want to get

```
abc_foo_def
abc_bar1_def
abc_bar2_def
abc_bar3_def
```

### Trial 1

I tried a macro with `Ctrl + D` (duplicate line) go to the bottom line and start of "foo", press delete 3 times, then write "bar1", repeat until bar3. Note that even if this worked, it wouldn't work for multiple "foo"s in input line. However it does not work as expected.

### Trial 2

Another macro was tried with duplicating, selecting the second line, Search & Replace "foo" with "bar", with `In Selection` checkbox checked. But I think it doesn't apply for macros.

So I'm looking for a reliable way.
Thanks for any help!

### P.S. 1

I'm also ok with a solution without Notepad++. (Excel, Word, whatever)

### P.S. 2

My input string can contain more than one "foo". Each one should be replaced with "barx"

Comment: How often are you doing this to how many strings? If only a few, I would just use Notepad++'s multi-line editing features without a macro. If a lot, Excel `find` and concatenation functions can build your strings. If other conditions are met, a regex in Notepad++ could do it.

Comment: In the absence of another of these solutions working for you, I would personally write a Python script to do it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/

Comment: @Dane thanks for your help. I don't know much python. And it could be a good answer if you clarify the "multiline editing features" in your first comment. In my case I usually need to add 4 lines, so foo + bar1 to bar4. It is a small string, but I'm getting tired of doing it manually every time. It is actually a line of -long- MATLAB code to be applied for 5 different variables. so foo is the name of the first variable and bar's are the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your Trial 2 failed. Perhaps you used your mouse when recording the macro? I'm pretty sure you get better results if you only use the keyboard when recording a macro.

I just recorded the following macro in Notepad++ 6.6.9. It works for a variable number of "foo" strings in the source line.

- Set the cursor at the beginning of the source line

Record:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (for find & replace)
- Find "foo" and replace with "bar1"; select "In Selection"; click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
- Close the dialog
- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (for find & replace)
- Find "foo" and replace with "bar2"; select "In Selection"; click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
- Close the dialog
- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (for find & replace)
- Find "foo" and replace with "bar3"; select "In Selection"; click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
- Close the dialog

End Recording

Here's the XML from `%AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`:

```
<Macro name="SuperUser_Q_Macro" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
  <Action type="0" message="2469" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2469" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2469" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2453" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2300" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2315" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="foo" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="bar1" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="898" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2453" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2300" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2315" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="foo" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="bar2" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="898" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2453" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2300" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="0" message="2315" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="foo" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="bar3" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="898" sParam="" /> 
  <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" /> 
</Macro>
```

Comment: Hi, of course I used the keyboard for all trials. Is there any way you can send me this macro? Maybe it is saved as an xml file somewhere. If not, I will try your solution. Thanks ! edit: Now I look and see that the only difference is that you have selected "In selection" in every S&R. maybe that's the key.